# Add value of subquery in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a really strange situation with the subquery.
Value of subquery is calculated but assigned value to property is different

```
var ozForAllViews = from oz in dbContext.oz
                where
                    oz.TId == 6050
                select
                    new ozForAllView
                    {
                        ozId = oz.ozId,
                        Ilosc = oz.Ilosc - (from pz in dbContext.pz
                            where
                                pz.Aktywny &&
                                pz.ozId == oz.ozId
                            select pz).Sum(z=> (decimal?) z.Ilosc) ?? 0
                    };
```

My property Ilosc is not calculated properly, value in DB equals 5.
But returned value is always 0.
Why is that oz.Ilosc is not subtracted from subquery?
I mean that 5 - 0 should equals 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround the expression that calculates the subtracted amount by parentheses:

```
from oz in dbContext.oz
where oz.TId == 6050
select
new ozForAllView
{
    ozId = oz.ozId,
    Ilosc = oz.Ilosc - ((from pz in dbContext.pz
        where
            pz.Aktywny &&
            pz.ozId == oz.ozId
        select pz).Sum(z=> (decimal?) z.Ilosc) ?? 0)
};
```

This is because the query is translated into SQL. In SQL, if one part of an expression is `null`, the whole expression is null. Your query is translated such that `oz.Ilosc - (from ... (decimal?) z.Ilosc)` is evaluated as one expression. That part becomes `null` when the subtracted amount is null and hence it will be returned as `0`.

It's confusing because in plain C# code, the behavior would be different. There the `?? 0` part would be applied to the subtracted amount only.